# MySQL suddenly broken after restart

Tags: php, mysql, database

I restarted my raspberry pi and now then I got this error on my website:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

I look at sudo service mysql status and I can see this.

```
Jan 09 17:34:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jan 09 17:34:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 09 17:34:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Has it updated and installed MariaDB? Because I was just using MYSQL i thought.

Can anyone help me fix this, my website is down and lots of people are trying to use it, I need to get it up for tonight.

Error log for mysql:

```
Jan 09 17:34:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jan 09 17:34:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 09 17:34:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Systemctl output

```
Jan 09 17:12:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jan 09 17:12:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jan 09 17:12:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 09 17:12:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jan 09 17:12:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 09 17:12:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB database server.
Jan 09 17:12:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jan 09 17:12:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jan 09 17:12:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jan 09 17:12:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 09 17:12:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jan 09 17:12:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 09 17:12:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB database server.
Jan 09 17:12:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jan 09 17:12:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jan 09 17:12:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jan 09 17:12:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 09 17:12:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jan 09 17:12:51 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 09 17:12:51 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB database server.
Jan 09 17:12:51 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jan 09 17:12:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jan 09 17:12:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
lines 1-32
```

Comment: Could you run `journalctl -u mariadb.service` and [edit] in the output? That might have more extensive logs.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I have edited in the systemctl output. Its the same. Im sure I was using INNODB Engine before. How can I get it back?

Comment: First, you should probably check if MySQL is currently installed (run `dpkg -l | grep mysql`, and see if you can spot `mysql-server`). If it is, you could try uninstalling MariaDB and see if that helps (be sure to back up as appropriate first).

Comment: @Aurora0001 I tried installing MariaDB but when I go to uninstall mariadb-common it said MySQL has unmet dependencies. I’ve heard that raspbian stretch changed the database format. So I’m guessing that’s what’s caused the error. If I go to reinstall MySQL it said it wants to install mariadb with it. So I’m wondering how to install the old version which I think used innoDB

Comment: How do you think I can do this?

Comment: InnoDB is just a storage engine included in MySQL; you won't need to directly install it yourself, as long as MySQL is installed. You could try uninstalling both MySQL and MariaDB (`apt-get remove mysql-* mariadb*`) then reinstalling MySQL to see if that helps.